# Unable to Send Large Files Over XMODEM

Tags: linux, display, serial

I'm trying to send a file to a serial device using XMODEM from within a screen terminal. It works just fine with small (633 bytes) but fails when I try to send a larger file (3.3 kilobytes).

This is two consecutive attempts:

```
eLua# recv /wo/hello.lua
Waiting for file ... CCCSending Documents/Telit/HelloT2.lua, 25 blocks: Give your local XMODEM receive command now.
Xmodem sectors/kbytes sent:   0/ 0kRetry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: Retry Count Exceeded

Transfer incomplete
XMODEM error
eLua# recv /wo/hello.lua
Waiting for file ... CCSending Documents/Telit/HelloT2.lua, 25 blocks: Give your local XMODEM receive command now.
Xmodem sectors/kbytes sent:   0/ 0kRetry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: NAK on sector
Retry 0: Cancelled

Transfer incomplete
error
```

From what I can tell this should be solved by disabling software flow control (XON/XOFF), but I've tried that, several ways, and it still doesn't work. I've tried: running "stty -xon -xoff", entering "C-a, f" in screen (tried all modes: "+flow", "-flow", and ""+flow(auto)"), as well as using command line arguments for screen "-fn". None of it seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you intent to send a Lua script to a Telit BlueMod+S42 with Bluetoth Module with Lua capable Firmware you should enable hardware flow control. BTW: looking at your log you might use an outdated Firmware Version and might update the Module